# Reproject pseudo Plate-Carree to "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" using GDALWARP

Tags: gdal, extents, gdalwarp, proj, epsg

Reproject pseudo Plate-Carree to "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" with gdalwarp.

I am trying to reproject a plate-carree to ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area".
I suspect ISEA requires a specific projection/epsg as input but I am baffled.
The input image seems to have geodetic coordinates but I cannot work out how to give the gdalwarp command any pixel extents.

The following GDAL command throws ERROR 1

```
gdalwarp -te -180 -90 +180 +90 -t_srs "+proj=isea +orient=pole +mode=plane +lon_0=0 +lat_0=0 " pseudo_plate_carree.tif ISEA.tif

ERROR 1: Too many points (900 out of 900) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.

# These commands for other projections work flawlessly:

# EQC TO CEA
gdalwarp  -t_srs "+proj=cea +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_ts=0" plate-carree-4087-eqc.tif out-4087.tif

gdalwarp  -t_srs "+proj=cea +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_ts=0" plate-carree-4326-pseudo.tif out-4326.tif

# PLATE-CARREE TO IGH
gdalwarp  -t_srs "+proj=igh " plate-carree-4326-pseudo.tif out-4326igh.tif

# PLATE-CARREE TO MOLLWEIDE
gdalwarp  -t_srs "+proj=moll " plate-carree-4326-pseudo.tif out-4326mol.tif


# My input GEOTIFF:
gdalinfo pseudo_plate_carree.tif

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: pseudo_plate_carree.tif
Size is 2550, 1427
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.141176470588235,-0.126138752627891)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=2550x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=2550x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=2550x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

---

The GDAL Library gdal-3.8.3 does not yet include the ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" projection. I do not know why the error does not point this out but gives this

`ERROR 1: Too many points (N out of N) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds`

With other unincluded projections such as "imoll", the error is

`Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument): Unknown projection`